# If use method like this int Add(int a,int b) and float Add(float a,float b) this is method overriding or not

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

If I have methods like this
int Add(int a,int b)
float Add(float a,float b)

This is method overloading or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is overloaded because the method names are the same.

You can refer to the definition here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading